# User keeps requesting JS-only route as HTML.. how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, http

I keep seeing this error in my logs every few hours. It's not often, but happens sometimes:

```
Missing template songs/purchase, application/purchase with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}
```

The interesting thing, is the ONLY way this route can be hit is with a `remote: true` link that they click in my Rails app. jQuery-UJS is loaded in the `<head>` of the document, so it's not like they're clicking a link before JS is loaded or before it's been bound to be sent via AJAX or something. How are normal people (these aren't GET requests submitted via a bot or curl or anything), using regular browsers (Chrome, etc., I can see what browsers it is), requesting this via HTML instead of JS?

Comment: Bots can impersonate browser, just need to add user agents.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that something is crawling the site asking for HTML. You can enforce not rendering HTML with
`format.html { render layout: false }`.